# graphql type error property "some" undefined

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

i am a beginer to start a graphql project i have created index.js file and i write some code after reading documentation here is my code

```
import express from 'express';
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
import resolvers from './resolver'
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs ,resolvers});
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
app.listen(8080);
```

and this is my schema.js code

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql `
type Query{
    hi:String
}`
module.export =typeDefs
```

here is my resolver file

```
export default{
    Query:{
        hi:(parent,args,context,info) =>'hi'
    },
}
```

Comment: follow some tutorial with working example/repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `apollo-server-express` package so that you can use [applyMiddleware](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#applymiddleware) method.

E.g.

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
const app = express();

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hi: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hi: () => 'hi',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Apollo server started at http://localhost:8080'));
```

Output:

```
 ⚡  curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"query": "query {hi}"}' http://localhost:8080/graphql
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21
ETag: W/"15-3MWwR0/DgM8B4VCmB0O7NSgG144"
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2021 02:51:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"data":{"hi":"hi"}}
```